# Import DAT Files into Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, import, restore

I Recently received a DAT file containing a SQL database, i would like to restore the database into my server for testing purposes, i tried to add it with the Task->Restore->Database but it didn't come up as a valid file when browsing for the DAT file, then if i select it with the "all files" option it will tell me that the file format is invalid.   Does anyone know how to load those kinds of files into SQL Server 2008?

Thanks

Comment: If the file is not too big, try to open it of to show a preview of the file. It can be anything in a .dat file.
Maybe it is using CSV format and you can insert you data using a bulk insert.

Comment: i tried but it is not human readable

Comment: Is your .dat from a sql server database ? It it the same version ? Maybe there are migration tools from older versions of SQL Server ?

Comment: Yeah, im pretty sure that this is a sql server database, not sure how it was generated, i'll try to get confirmation on which tool was used to generate those files.  Because as you said... within a DAT file it can be anything... from cvs to god knows what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually [this](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting047.htm) was the issue.  the DAT was a normal .Bak, but the file became corrupted while uploading\downloading from an FTP server... Weird

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Just had this exact error and found a much simpler fix.

Change the extension to `.txt` from `.dat` and then import the file via the import wizard built into SQL Server or via SSIS. To my understanding the solution in your link should only be necessary for `.bak` files.